# Breaking a circular dependency with C++ concepts and CRTP

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, crtp

I want to be able to do:

```cpp
template<typename T>  // line 8
class Base;

template<typename T>
concept C = std::is_base_of_v<Base<T>,T>;

template<C T>         // line 17
class Base {
    // ...
};

// ...

class MyClass : public Base<MyClass> {
    // ...
};
```

That is, have a template class `Base` that takes as its template parameter the class that's deriving from it (the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)). I want a concept `C` to constrain the template type `T` of `Base` such that `T` is derived from `Base<T>`.

However, this won't compile because:

```
x.cpp:17:10: error: type constraint differs in template redeclaration
template<C T>
         ^
```

I'd have to forward-declare `Base` on line 8 using `C` instead of `typename` — but I haven't declared `C` yet and you can't forward-declare concepts.

So how can I get what I want?

Comment: 1. This doesn't seem to be a complete error message. 2. The shown code doesn't have `template<Singleton T>`.

Comment: @JeJo I don't understand your question. Anywhere I constrain a template parameter to `C`, I want said parameter to be a class derived from `Base`.

Answer (score 5):

You can not get what you want because at the point of instantiation `public Base<MyClass>` child class `MyClass` is still incomplete so you get Undefined Behavior when checking `is_base_of`.

As an alternative, you can put corresponding `static_assert` in body of some of the `Base` method so it will be checked later.